# SourceTree / git add - Fail to stage modified files

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-add, git-stage

I use SourceTree daily and never had such issue.  But today I did some minor change and now I ended up having this issue:

What I changed today?

I added p4Merge as merge tool and diff tool in my git config.  Then I changed my mind and deleted entries for p4Merge from my /.gitconfig file since I noticed I ended up having double entries for merge and diff tools there.

Here is how that looked

[image]

However, after removing all entries for p4Merge tool, I noticed that I am unable to stage files from SourceTree anymore.  Below screenshot shows that I have 4 upstaged files.  If I try to stage them by checking off the checkbox beside them, nothing will happen.  The wont be moved to Staged files section

[image]

**UPDATE**

Using `git add .` also does nothing and I notice that terminal shows files as modified but they are not red nor green but purple:

[image]

Comment: What do you see in command-line? `git status`? Would `git add . ` return an error?

Comment: git add . returns no error when issuing git status.  Same behavior like in SourceTree, issuing git add . does nothing, but it is interesting, in terminal, the modified 4 files show as "modified" but they are neither red nor green but purple.  Will attach image in a sec to question above

Comment: Is there any .gitmodules with smudge/clean directive in them?

Comment: no idea what you are asking, new to git

Comment: Just asking if you see any .gitmodules in your git repo files

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this issue, I renamed one of the files above.

Next I issued `git status` and that saw the original file as deleted and new file with new name added

`git add .` worked this time and I added file

Then I issued `git commit -m "message"` to commit change

Then I changed name back and did `git add . / git commit -m "message"` again and that fixed all files, not only the one I renamed.

Comment: Unfortunally, I thought I fixed it with my answer above but the issue is reoccuring so the fix is just temporary looks like.  it almost looks like something is being cached some place else and keeps comming back